# Is casting an array to string "special" among other types?

Tags: arrays, string, casting, chapel

In this code, I am casting an integer array `arr` to several different types. When casting to `real`, the result is an array obtained by casting each element to `real`. And the same happens for `complex`. But if I cast `arr` to `string`, the result becomes a scalar variable of `string`. This was a bit surprising to me because I initially expected an array of string...

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
writeln( arr );
writeln( arr.type:string );

var r = arr : real;
writeln( r );
writeln( r.type:string );

var z = arr : complex;
writeln( z );
writeln( z.type:string );

var s = arr : string;
writeln( s );
writeln( s.type:string );
```

(Result with chpl-1.20)

```
1.0 2.0 3.0
[domain(1,int(64),false)] real(64)
1.0 + 0.0i 2.0 + 0.0i 3.0 + 0.0i
[domain(1,int(64),false)] complex(128)
1 2 3
string
```

However, because string is used in I/O (e.g. `writeln(arr)`), I guess casting to string may be "exceptional" or "special" among other types. If so, is it reasonable to assume that `arr : T` always gives a new array of element type `T` if `T` is not `string` and conversion of each element to `T` is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your assumptions are correct.  When an array is cast to type `string`, a single string value results because (a) it's possible to represent the array as a string, (b) that cast is supported, and (c) as you note, we need this capability for things like I/O.  This is true of most types, so the rule that "wins" for this case is "expressions of arbitrary types generally support being cast to a string in Chapel."

In contrast, when an array of `int` is cast to `real` (say) there is no cast defined from arrays to reals.  However, there is a cast defined from `int` to `real`, so Chapel's array promotion rules kick in and the cast is applied to each array element in parallel.  Effectively, the expression `arr: real` is rewritten as `[e in arr] e: real`.

This also suggests a way that you could get the array of string result if that is what you wanted for a specific case: iterate over the array, casting each element to string ([TIO](https://tio.run/##S85ILEjN@f@/LLFIIbGoSMFWIdpQx0jHONaaq7wosyQ1J08DLK6JytcrqSxItSouKcrMSwfJcYH0F4N0pypk5oFUxCqkKlgpQFQg6S1GMakYzZz//wE)):

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
writeln( arr );
writeln( arr.type:string );

var s = [e in arr] e:string;
writeln( s );
writeln( s.type:string );
```

(and this form should work uniformly for any legal cast on the element type, it's just a bit more typing than the shorthand that promotion enables; but in a generic setting, this could be appropriate).